# Some similarities between permutations and numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it possible to have some similarities between the **permutations** in group theory and **natural numbers** in number theory? The first similarities can be the following:

1- Every permutation is the product of its *cycles*. Also, every number is product of *prime numbers*.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a great thing to think about.  In fact, I believe this is the whole point of abstract algebra.  What algebraic sets are the same, what are the differences between them.  Your observation that any permutation can be written as a product if cycles is indeed true; however, I would ask you about the uniqueness of these.  The fact that every natural number can be written *uniquely* as a product of primes is pretty important.  This is not true for permutations unfortunately. For instance,
$$(123)=(12)(23)=(12)(12)(12)(23)=(12)(23)(23)(23)=(12)(12)(12)(23)(23)(23) =\ldots$$

Comment: But every permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles. This uniqueness is similar to the numbers.